# App Identity - relationship between app id and access token

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am new to OAuth and I am working on app identity/[client credential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) work flow using OAuth. Basically there will be a client application calling the API using the client app's app id. The API will trust whoever have the access to the client app. 
[image]

The understand I have for the implementation is that:

1. register client app to Azure AD
2. put the app id of the client app into the API
3. enable OAuth request so the client app is able to receive access token from AAD
4. use the access token to call the API

But my confusion is the relationship between the web app's app id and the access token. I know we have to put the client's app id into the API so the API can somehow recognize the client app. **How does the API know the access token is from that specific app id?** How does it work exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app id also named client id, it represents a client application which makes protected resource requests on behalf of the resource owner.

The client application authenticates the resource owner and obtains its authorization, then the authorization server will issue the access token to the client application.

For more details about the relationship, you could see the [Azure Active Directory developer glossary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/developer-glossary#access-token).

**Update**:

For example, I use the client credential flow to get the access token for MS Graph API. Then I decode it in https://jwt.io/ . You will find the claims `"aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com/"`, `"appid": "xxxxxx"`, `"app_displayname": "joywebapp2"`, for more details, see [Claims in access tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#claims-in-access-tokens).

The you use the access token to call MS Graph API, it will know the access token is from that specific client app as you asked.

[image]

Comment: The part between users and client app authentication I understand. But how does the API know the access token is from that specific client app?

Comment: @WWpana The token will include the claims including its permissions, you could decode the access token in https://jwt.io/ to see the details.

Comment: @WWpana You could refer to the sample in my update.

Comment: It makes sense. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

There is a dedicated protocol/validation mechanism for this. Once token is received at resource server (ex:- API as in your example), it can perform a token introspection to identify the context of the token. [OAuth 2.0 Token Introspection](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662) define how the introspection request should be build and what to expect from response.

> This specification defines a protocol that allows authorized
> protected resources to query the authorization server to determine
> the set of metadata for a given token that was presented to them by
> an OAuth 2.0 client.

Read through the [introspection response section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662#section-2.2) to identify what sort of data it will return. Client ID is also some valid claim.

Now there is an alternative approach too. This is what Azure AD has adopted. Azure Active Directory use JWT formatted access tokens.

**[Azure Active Directory access tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens)**

> Access tokens enable clients to securely call APIs protected by Azure. Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) access tokens are JWTs, Base64 encoded JSON objects signed by Azure. Clients should treat access tokens as opaque strings, as the contents of the token are intended for the resource only.

JWT tokens are self contained, which mean the holder/receiver can validate the integrity of the token and verify claims valid. Go through [token validation section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#validating-tokens) which explain the complete process. One key claim you must focus is the `audience` claim. This denote the intended audience of JWT and can have multiple values (array).